# Update Data stock after the purchase on CodeIgniter with Library Cart

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to build an e-commerce system but I can constraints, so when The purchase of goods then the database will reduce the field of stock, after I try, but the result does not fit, what's wrong?

Controllers

```
function purchase {
        foreach($this->cart->contents() as $item)
        {
            $data = array(
                    'id_product' => $item['id'],
                    'name_product' => $item['name'],
                    'quatity'       => $item['qty'],
                    'price'     => $item['price'],
            );

        $data = array(  
                    'stock' => -$item['qty']    
                    );  
        $this->db->where('id_product', $item['id']);
        $this->db->update('tbproduct', $data);  

        }

}
```

Comment: you want `stock=total-quantity` to save in database.

Comment: does there is filed `total` in database?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati, yes true

Comment: and you want to do that for every items.

Comment: yes because I am an array of data so all the data is reduced in accordance array

Comment: `print_r($this->cart->contents());` try this...how many items you see in array?

Comment: not whether it was to show all the cart?

Comment: ok try like below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this....

```
$items = $this->cart->contents();
function purchase {
        foreach( $items as $item)
        {
            $stock=$item['stock']-$item['qty'];

            $data = array(
                    'id_product' => $item['id'],
                    'name_product' => $item['name'],
                    'quatity'       => $item['qty'],
                    'price'     => $item['price'],
                    'stock' => $stock
            );

        $this->db->where('id_product', $item['id']);
        $this->db->update('tbproduct', $data);  

        }

}
```

Comment: this `$stock=$item['stock']-$item['qty'];` /  `$item['stock']` on my chart in the data does not exist?

Comment: thanks bro, I try to edit your answer and successful results